rails NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for an instanciated Class object
class Parti < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :aggregateparti, optional: true
  belongs_to :serving_table
  belongs_to :billing_option, class_name: 'Categoryminor'

  has_many   :covers, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :serving_table_name
end

controller action
class PartisController < ApplicationController
[...]
  def create
    serving_table = ServingTable.where(shop_id: @shop.id, name: params[:parti][:serving_table_name]).first
    params[:parti][:serving_table_id] = serving_table.id
    params[:parti][:shop_id] = @shop.id
binding.break 
    @parti = Parti.new(parti_params)
binding.break 

[...]
    def parti_params
      params.require(:parti).permit(:shop_id, :aggregateparti_id, :serving_table_id, :serving_table_name, :consumer_id, :server_id, :covers, :children_covers, :billing_option_id)
    end

the error remains whether :serving_table_name is present or not amongst the strong_params.
The log registers after params submission od   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "parti"=>{"serving_table_name"=>"1", "covers"=>"1", "children_covers"=>"1", "billing_option_id"=>"199"}, "commit"=>"Let's go!"} the error
NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for an instance of String):
Running  in the console:
@parti = Parti.new(serving_table_id: 2, covers: 1, children_covers: 1, billing_option_id: 199, shop_id: 1)
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:241:in `replace': undefined method `each' for an instance of Integer (NoMethodError)

        other_array.each { |val| raise_on_type_mismatch!(val) }

Parti
=> Parti(id: integer, shop_id: integer, aggregateparti_id: integer,  
serving_table_id: integer, consumer_id: integer, server_id: integer,  
covers: integer, children_covers: integer, billing_option_id: integer,  
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

I find a type mismatch hard to believe, as all non-rails-managed attributes are integers.
Rails 7.1.3.2
ruby 3.3.0
In stepping through each step of the process, the blockage appears to fire at
   254|     private
   255|       # Override <tt>AbstractController::Base#process_action</tt> to run the
   256|       # <tt>process_action</tt> callbacks around the normal behavior.
   257|       def process_action(...)
=> 258|         run_callbacks(:process_action) do
   259|           super
   260|         end
   261|       end
   262|   end
=>#0    AbstractController::Callbacks#process_action at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:258 #=> nil
  #1    ActionController::Rescue#process_action at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:25
  # and 73 frames (use `bt' command for all frames)
(rdbg)
[22, 31] in ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb
    22|
    23|     private
    24|       def process_action(*)
    25|         super
    26|       rescue Exception => exception
=>  27|         request.env["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?
    28|         rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
    29|       end
    30|   end
    31| end
=>#0    ActionController::Rescue#process_action at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:27
[and shortly later]
=> 167|       self.class.rescue_with_handler exception, object: self
[...]
=>#0    ActiveSupport::Rescuable#rescue_with_handler(exception=#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each' ...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.2/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:167
  #1    ActionController::Rescue#process_action at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:28

What is be going on here?
Update / answer
There is a naming conflict. has_many   :covers does not mesh with the fact the class has an attribute with the name covers.
Renaming the attribute quantity_covers allows the processing of submitted params, while maintaining the relationship rails (in addition to the database) has.
bonus info  This error, without the has_many specification does not manifest itself, however the rails processing of the action is, as expected in Rails 7, no longer defaulting to turbo_stream, but html ...

@partee.create is your issue, as @partee is an instance of Partee and does not have a create method. Usually this would be handled has @partee = Partee.new(your_params_here) followed by @partee.save or Partee.create(your_params_here). As for your second issue "undefined method each for an instance of String" you would need to provide debugging details. Please also note that generally speaking params are whitelisted using the StrongParameters interface.

create is not an instance method. It is a method on a class.  The other error is related to something in your Partee model which you have not provided.

@engineersmnky  I have re-cast the question, by actually starting from scratch (out of excessive security) fully adopting the rails-way, yet hitting the same issue.  The model is shown as is some debugging data.

@Jerome the relationship with covers is a has_many but you are passing the number 1. If you change this to an Array e.g. covers: [1] it should work

or rename the variable to avoid the confusion...  because it is meant as a quantity (for further processing each 'cover' ...
